# Maximal Ideal of a ring.

Tags: ring-theory

Suppose if $M$ is maximal ideal of $R$ and $a \notin M$, than what can we say about $ M+(a)$?

I studied this from book: The ideal $M + (a)$ contains $M$ so, since $M$ is maximal, this ideal must be all of $R$.

How?

Comment: $M+(a)$ is not the coset $M+a$. It's the sum of two ideals. Here, $(a)$ means the ideal generated by $a$.

Comment: Why do you ask a question about rings and ideals, and tag it group-theory?

Comment: @Gerry: I fixed the tag.

Answer (score 8):

$M\subsetneqq M+(a)$, since $a\in\big(M+(a)\big)\setminus M$, so $M+(a)$ is an ideal properly containing $M$. But $M$ is a maximal ideal, so by definition the only ideal properly containing $M$ is the whole ring $R$. Therefore $M+(a)=R$.